# What is the TextBox's touch event in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, textbox, touch, silverlight-5.0

I'm working on a Silverlight 5 application, which is supposed to be deployed on a touch-screen interface. The Button click events are raised correctly on the touch screen as far as I know (I do not have access to a touch screen).

But, what event is raised on touching a SL5 Textbox? The Textbox does not have a click event.

Also, what event in raised on touching a textblock?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseLeftButtonDown event.